# Retrieving Rails 3 model with XML column

Tags: xml, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, db2, activemodel

I have a Rails 3 model that includes a XML column in the database (IBM DB2). Whenever I try to retrieve this model in the XML format by `@model.to_xml`, I get as result the XML column escaped, something like this:

```
<model>
    <id>1</id>
    <xml-column>&lt;tag&gt;value&lt;/tag&gt;</xml-column>
</model>
```

What I'm trying to achieve is the following:

```
<model>
    <id>1</id>
    <xml-column>
        <tag>value</tag>
    </xml-column>
</model>
```

I tried some stuff unsuccessfully so far, like unescaping the XML column and rewriting the `to_xml` method (I'm not sure how to efficiently parse the XML column).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That solved:

```
def to_xml(options = {})
  options[:indent] ||= 2
  xml = options[:builder] ||= Builder::XmlMarkup.new(:indent => options[:indent])
  xml.instruct! unless options[:skip_instruct]

  xml.model do
    xml.id self.id    
    xml.metadata do
      xml.target! << self.metadata
    end
  end
end
```

:)

Comment: FYI I am using Rails 3.1.1 and Builder::XmlMarkup threw the error "NameError: uninitialized constant ActiveRecord::Associations::Builder::XmlMarkup" what fixed it for me was using ::Builder::XmlMarkup.

Answer (score 0):

Could you do something like:

```
def to_xml
   super(:except => [:column-xml]).merge!({:column-xml => self.column-xml})
end
```

I haven't tried this FYI